# How to increase nvme_core.io_timeout on my c5 EC2 instacnce

Tags: linux, kernel, aws, modprobe, nvme

We have mesos cluster where we're running centos7 `c5` instances on aws. The kernel version is the latest `4.16.1-1`.

In `c5` instance type the volumes uses `nvme drivers`. The nvme volumes seems to have a behavior as mentioned [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17097804) where `if there is an io timeout on a volume, the volume mount becomes read only and no further writes can happen. So if there is heavy read-write operations on your device like on root drive then after the io timeout no further writes can happen so its dangerous.`

In AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/nvme-ebs-volumes.html#timeout-nvme-ebs-volumes) it mentioned to set an io timeout as high as possible and it seems to be `4294967295 sec`.

AWS doc specify that `default io timeout` is `30sec`, but it is max `255 sec` for `kernel prior to 4.15 version` and `4294967295 sec for kernel 4.15+.` As we have `latest 4.16.1 kernel` we should set it to max `4294967295 sec`.

But when I try to set the `nvme_core.io_timeout` parameter to the max value, it didn't get refelected. I tried this

```
sh-4.2# modprobe nvme_core io_timeout=123457
sh-4.2# cat /sys/module/nvme_core/parameters/io_timeout
30
sh-4.2#
```

What is the correct way to set `nvme_core.io_timeout` I tried lot of other things like

1. setting it in `/etc/default/grub` file
2. sysctl command
3. Overriding `/sys/module/nvme_core/parameters/io_timeout` file

But Nothing helped.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my own experimentation, we do this while building our AMIs.

`cp /etc/default/grub /tmp/grub
cat >>/tmp/grub <<'EOF'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} nvme_core.io_timeout=255"
EOF
sudo mv /tmp/grub /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub`

Then create an AMI from the instance. When you start a new EC2 instance from the AMI, it comes up with the correct setting.

Obviously this can be modify to set any kernel parameter.